# How could a single individual warn the following civilization after the fall of our current one?

Tags: alternate-history, apocalypse, near-future, post-apocalypse, civilization

*Reviewers: reformulation [according to this](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49) is done if the post is not okay yet, suggestions are welcomed in comments*

The limits of the individual:

- has no access to the mass media.
- has the average financial resources what a commoner has in a Western state.

The mindset:

- knows that some social apocalypse nears.
- knows that is the result of the social manipulations of an X group.
- knows that it is unlikely that his/her civilization will survive.

Here I would show an analogy: in the last centuries of the ancient Roman Empire, it was already more or less known, that with time, the Empire will fall. It was a significant change in the mindset; some centuries earlier the "common knowledge" was that the empire will last forever. The ancient Romans weren't dummies: they didn't know a lot, what we know, but they already knew the world map and their history.

Now back to the present. So, there is knowledge, that he/she belongs likely to the last generation of his/her people, and to the last generation of his/her civilization.

[image]

The apocalypse won't be a sudden, catastrophic event, rather a long process, a protracted series of small events, and a continuous decrease of the living standards and all significant indicators what could show the development of a civilization.

Rome or Asimov's Trantor was dying centuries long, the time scale of the fall of the civilization seems some decade long. And the historians of the future will see the era of *the dying of your civilization*.

However, contrary to Asimov's Trantor, or to the ancient Roman Empire, the cause of the fall is this time *not a complex structure of social, demographic and political mechanisms*. This time, the cause of the fall is a

- very conscient
- very determined
- very manipulative
- very well-organized

action of a small, well definable, but anyways nearly invisible group. We could call them "group X". Contrary the conspiration theories, the difference is that this "group X" is really existing (or at least the individual thinks they are).

It seems likely, that some centuries later, a new civilization, a new highly developed era will likely grow on the remains of the current world. It seems probable that this "group X" will be likely active also at this time.

The individual has some decades lifetime back. He/she can, and want to sacrifice these decades *to somehow warn this following civilization*.

**How could he do this?**

Note: actually, it is a pragmatic thing - the goal is to reach the *possible largest effect* in this far future, as the effect of this *warning*, even if this effect is small on the global level.

---

*About "group X":* it is a very well determined group, working as a loosely coupled social network connected by various (sometimes contradictory) ideologies since at least millennia. Nobody knows, where are they from, nobody knows, *why* are they doing this. Their most characteristic properties:

- they don't consider the human as "real" humans, only themselves
- although they are probably humans with ordinary human skills
- they are very sensitive to the blood loss in *their* group
- they consider the rest of the humanity as dangerous, semi-intelligent animals
- they have a cultural heritage preferring [soft power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_power), background jobs
- they have a strong urge to remain invisible
- they like to "use" others for the background, occupying influential positions (mass media, political decision-making and so on), or controlling people in these positions, mainly by their immoral wishes
- they are capable and willing to plan in centuries and execute these plans.

Comment: Are there some specific details that you know (which someone can independently verify) or the only knowledge is that the civilization is doomed, and it's all "annukakis"'s fault?

Comment: @Alexander (We could call them "group X", it sounds better). The cause of the apocalypse is mainly social manipulations caused by "group X", which is a nearly invisible but very influental social network. Their (intentional, well-planned) effect to the global society is that science, education, health deteriates to a medieval level. They do this with the goal to cement their own power until the eternity, although the result of their deeds will be the fall of the civilization what they are manipulating.

Comment: But would you know any hard facts about "group X"? How can you sound any different than many of the conspiracy theorists?

Comment: @Alexander Yes - they are (probably) not superhumans, they are more like a very effective, influental cult of ordinary humans. Their invisibility is not perfect. If they would be pefectly invisible, they couldn't really do anything. There are well-known people from them it is rumored they *may* belong to them, there are seemingly independent events showing somehow into the same direction, while an "external influence" can be strongly suspected, and so on. However, they are practically invisible *for the majority of the population*. The secrecy plays a vital role in their self-defense.

Comment: Those facts are general rather than specific. Without specific, verifiable facts it would be really impossible to convince anybody that this is not just another conspiracy theory.

Comment: In popular fiction, members of "group X" should have some unique vulnerability, which either allows to show their true nature to everybody, or to kill them in an unusual way. Protagonist makes a public demonstration, and everybody starts to believe that aliens (vampires, ghosts etc.) are real.

Comment: @Alexander A potential key element of the story could be, if the "hero" actually never learns if his/her efforts would be wasted on this reason. But it is about the story. It relates to the world, that in such a world, only the matter of opinion, if "group X" exists or not. It is similar to the [Brotherhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brotherhood_(Nineteen_Eighty-Four)) of 1984, although it plays an opposite role. About the question: the essential part is, *what could the "hero" do*, not if that "group X" is actually real or not.

Comment: @Alexander There is no known way to show their "true" origin, on all known measurements they are ordinary human. Their behavior, and sometimes their mistakes, clearly show that they are human, although it makes also their success and effectivity unexplainable. There is no rational answer also for this contradiction. Side remark: if you would see a youtube video showing that Ronald Reagan was a Klingon, would it affect your voting on the next election?

Comment: Just a reminder we have [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for refining your question before posting it to the main site. At this time you have 4 close votes, so next time better prepare it in the sandbox first to receive feedback.

Comment: I believe that no edit can salvage this question, without changing the actual question.

Comment: @Vylix Wonderful critic, except that you forgot to explain: *what is the problem with this question*. I believe, if there would be still one, you had mentioned it.

Comment: @MorningStar this asks about a story set in your world. That's why you have close votes as "too story based". How could he do it? That's asking for a plot, which is your job as the author. Everyone here will have different opinions on how to do that, and all will be true, without any measure to pick the best answer.

Comment: @MorningStar I have questions too, that is too story based. Don't worry, we all have done it. If you believe this question worthy is not story based, or you want suggestions on how to improve it, I suggest you post in meta and give the link to this question. Anyway, your story is interesting, too bad the question does not fit for SE Q&A format.

Comment: @MorningStar please do seek advice in meta; I love this question, but do not have enough SE-fu to vote it reopened.  The kind people in meta may be able to advise you.

Answer (score 4):

Your only hope is to bring this to the eyes of the governments because you yourself can not hope to ever deal with a group of people with more power than you. I would say if you have proof of their existence and there isn't a greater conspiracy, simply bringing attention to it and the police/FBI or w/e will eventually deal with them.

Comment: "group X" has already much stronger influence to the governments, because: 1) they are much better organized 2) much more resourceful 3) they have the best know-how in social manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Leave "Time-Capsules" with as many young honest people as you can.

Choose promising youths and entrust them with your knowledge, form a Resistance, a secret group who will keep their eys and ears open and will not be afraid to give their lives for the truth.

Be prepaired to die for the truth, to fight with all your strength, physical, mental and emotional, to ensure the results you wish for.

There's only so much you can do **completely** alone.

Comment: Good idea, but it requires *a lot of* time capsules (here comes the resource and time problem). Or time capsules which can be somehow very well targeted.

Comment: Another important thing: if you would find an old, latin scroll in the basement of your home, what chance would it have to significantly change your deeds *now*? You wouldn't even understand it. Likely you would take it to a museum, because some archeologist could maybe decipher it. And it is the best case.

Comment: @MorningStar sorry I wasn't more specific. By Time Capsules I meant knowledge you would give to the young people, you would speak to them, tell them all you know, share with them all the evidence, in turn they would do the same when their time came, share knowledge, pass it on. and all of you would fight in the background, calling the general population's attention to the truth as much as you could as often as possible. the more people are aware the more they will be prepaired.

Answer (score 2):

**Money**

First you need to make alot of money, with money you can get power. You just need to remember about what new product would become the next facebook/Whatsapp/Instagram and start investing in it.

**Power**

A few years pass and now you are in the top 0.1% thanks to this smart investments. Now you start this quest to track and kill this terrorist group without having to worry for resources.